# Routing attribute with fixed parameter value in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there any way to configure attribute routing with fixed parameter in .net core

```
[Route("TermsOfUse")] // ex: i need push default routing with id = 5
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id) { }
```

I found a way to use routes.MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "TermsOfUse", new { controller = "Article", action = "Details",  id=5 })
```

How to use attribute routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
[Route("TermsOfUse/{id=5}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id) { }
```

If no value for `id` is supplied then it will be 5.